# Replacing the vowels of a string with the letter "X"

Tags: strings, ruby, ruby-on-rails

This code replaces every vowel of the string with "X":

```
def vowel_censor(sentence)
    vowels = "aeiou".chars
    result = []
    sentence.chars.each do |charachter|
      if vowels.include?(charachter)
        result << "X"
      else
        result << charachter
      end
    end
    result.join("")
end


puts "---------Vowel Censor----------"
puts vowel_censor("Let's order a pizza") == "LXt's XrdXr X pXzzX"
puts vowel_censor("Nitwit, blubber, oddment, tweak") == "NXtwXt, blXbbXr, XddmXnt, twXXk"
puts vowel_censor("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious") == "SXpXrcXlXfrXgXlXstXcXxpXXlXdXcXXXs"
```

Answer (score 6):

Look into [regular expressions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html), which Ruby is very good at:

```
def vowel_censor(string)
  string.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, "X") # case-insensitive
end
```

Or, even easier, more low-level and more efficient, use [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
def vowel_censor(string)
  string.tr("aeiou", "X") # lowercase only; use "aeiouAEIOU" to handle both upper- and lowercase
end
```

For your current code:

- The Ruby convention is 2 spaces of indentation. Not 4 spaces, not tabs
- Your code doesn't handle uppercase vowels
- `join` doesn't need an argument in this case
- `charachter` is misspelt
- Don't create a variable (`result` in this case) and modify it from inside a block unless you really, *really* have to. Do something like this instead:

  ```
  sentence.chars.reduce([]) do |result, char| # reduce is also aliased as #inject
    result << vowels.include?(char) ? "X" : char
  end.join
  ```

  or (building a string instead of an array)

  ```
  sentence.chars.reduce("") do |result, char|
    result += vowels.include?(char) ? "X" : char
  end
  ```

  or (using a method similar to reduce)

  ```
  sentence.chars.each_with_object([]) do |result, char|
    result << vowels.include?(char) ? "X" : char
  end.join
  ```

Comment: Wow, thank you @Flambino! You are right, using a regular expression in this case is better!!

Comment: @JoanaB Yeah, regular expressions are incredibly useful, though in this case `String#tr` does the job just as well, without the (admittedly negligible) overhead of regex. Replacing characters in a string is _precisely_ what `tr` is built for; using regex is pretty overkill

Comment: Thank you @Flambino, it's the first time I'm hearing about #tr(it will be very useful from now on). Yes definitely, using #tr is easier than using regular expressions.

Comment: @JoanaB Yeah, `tr` is often overlooked - even though it's actually old as dirt: Its name comes from a standard unix/linux command line program also called [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)). Don't know when the CLI program appeared but I'm guessing ~40 years ago

Comment: This is interesting - 40 years is a lot!! I just wished it had another way of handling uppercase letters : )

Comment: Best use `<<` for string concatenation inside `reduce` loop. Using `+=` will create a new object for each iteration.